# Setting up CCNET security

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I am just learning all this stuff (CCNet), and have a simple working
ccnet.config, that successfully executes through the localhost/ccnet
service.  I am trying to get security set up so that users in other
locations can use cctray.  I added this to the ccnet.config file
(copied and modified from one of the security examples (internalSecurity)....

```
<cruisecontrol>
  <internalSecurity>
   <users>
     <!-- Authenticated users -->
     <passwordUser name="account1" display="me (Installer)"
 password="%account1"/>
   </users>
   <permissions>
     <!-- Roles -->
     <rolePermission name="Releasers" forceBuild="Allow"
defaultRight="Allow" viewProject="Allow">
       <users>
         <userName name="account1"/>
       </users>
     </rolePermission>
   </permissions>
 </internalSecurity>
 <project name="test project">
```

Now, when I click on the 'force' button on http://localhost/ccnet/ViewFarmReport.aspx,
I get the following exception message..."Request processing has failed
on the remote server.  Permission to execute ViewProject has been
denied.  I am not sure what is happening here.  I am logged onto the
server as 'account1', and, I have added viewProject="Allow" to the
rollPermission name="Releasers".

Comment: Obviously I did not get the 'enter code here' thing correct.  Was I not supposed to put it on every line?

Answer (score 2):

look at the docs here for security setup :
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Security_scenarios

Answer (score 1):

CCNet config looks right. You might try restarting the CCNET executable in order for it to pick up the config changes. Depends on how CCNET is set up in your case usually it needs a restart at the CCNET service on Windows.